# Sass - two classes in a single tag

Tags: css, sass

So, i need a style for

```
.question_actions.active
```

my existing CSS

```css
.question_actions {
    float: right;
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 110px; 
}
.question_action {
    margin-bottom: 8px; 
    padding: 3px;
}
.question_actions.active {
    /* some CSS */
}
```

what would be the syntax to combine them?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Here you go:

```css
.question_actions {
   float: right; 
   font-size: 1em;
   width: 110px; 

   .question_action {
       margin-bottom:8px;
       padding: 3px;
   }

   &.active {
    //some css
   }
}
```

Comment: Small note, the ampersand is whitespace sensitive. & .active with a space, won't be interpreted the same way.